# Installing a "battery controller" on my desktop motherboard

Tags: batteries

I'm currently working on a DIY tablet project which involves a low power desktop motherboard and a huge 40 Ah 12 V Lithium battery. My set up ATM involves:

1. 8* 3.3 V 20Ah batteries (series of 4, two of them connected in parallel)
2. [pico-PSU](http://www.mini-box.com/PicoPSU-120-WI-25-12-25V-DC-DC-ATX-power-supply) can take input of 12~25 V, 80~120 W ATX PSU
3. Mini ITX motherboard KTQM77/mITX

Now, I think this set-up is pretty simple, but I cannot think of a way to check the battery remaining and other stuffs over the Windows. Sure, I can get a battery display with a small micro-controller to check the remaining battery and so on, but I really want to get that laptop-like battery control interface. Can this be done?

Also, if you see any problems or suggestions with my rig, let me know-like 40Ah battery being a bit of overkill and so on.

Comment: How are you controlling the charging and discharging of the cells, Li-ion batteries can be dangerous if handled wrong.

Comment: I think -1 vote is just for you using Li-Ion batteries.
Do not demonize LiIon batteries that much of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked two questions.  Paraphrasing:

> I plan to do a 4S2P lithium-based battery system design.  Is my plan
>   OK?

It's certainly possible, but it doesn't sound like you've put any effort into designing a battery management system, which would need to address charge control, discharge limit, current limiting, temperature monitoring & management, etc.  If you haven't worked with Lithium chemistry batteries before, consider using a cheap, commonly available lead acid battery in your initial prototype - they're much easier to work with, are more forgiving and are generally safer without explicit battery management.

> I want to be able to monitor battery SOC (and do other thing) via
>   Windows OS.

Easy - simply design the microcontroller-based solution you mentioned in your post, then connect the microcontroller to the motherboard via RS232.  You'll need to design a simple communication protocol over the serial interface and will need to write a windows application to display SOC and provide whatever features you want, but the process is very straightforward.